# How to understand the Run and Job class definition in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

Here's how the Job class defined in Jenkins:

```
public abstract class Job <JobT extends Job<JobT, RunT>, RunT extends Run<JobT, RunT>>
    extends AbstractItem implements ExtensionPoint, StaplerOverridable, ModelObjectWithChildren {
```

the code comment as below

> /**
>    * A particular execution of {@link Job}.
>    *
>    * Custom {@link Run} type is always used in conjunction with
>    * a custom {@link Job} type, so there's no separate registration
>    * mechanism for custom {@link Run} types.
>    *
>    * @author Kohsuke Kawaguchi
>    * @see RunListener
>    */

and here's how the Run class defined in Jenkins:

```
public abstract class Run <JobT extends Job<JobT,RunT>,RunT extends Run<JobT,RunT>>
    extends Actionable implements ExtensionPoint, Comparable<RunT>, AccessControlled, PersistenceRoot, DescriptorByNameOwner, OnMaster {
```

the code comment as below:

> /**
>    * A job is an runnable entity under the monitoring of Hudson.
>    *
>    * Every time it "runs", it will be recorded as a {@link Run} object.
>    *
>    * To create a custom job type, extend {@link TopLevelItemDescriptor} and put {@link Extension} on it.
>    *
>    * @author Kohsuke Kawaguchi
>    */

Now I'm stuck in the

```
<JobT extends Job<JobT, RunT>, RunT extends Run<JobT, RunT>>
```

part. It looks weird(like a circular reference to each other) and for me, it's quite hard to understand. So, how to understand this kind of code design? Any suggestion or analysis would be welcome and appreciated. Thank you.